# Datatables - Get column data based on another column data

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have table in this format

```
c1    c2     c3      c4

1   True    row1   row1c4
2   True    row2   row2c4
3   False   row3   row3c4
4   False   row4   row4c4
```

I use this to filter out the col 4 data alone

```
var table = $('#statustable').DataTable();
var emaillist =
            table
                .columns('c4:name')
                .data()
                .eq( 0 )      // Reduce the 2D array into a 1D array of data
                .unique()     // Reduce to unique values
                .sort()       // Sort data alphabetically               
                .join( ',' );
```

Now I need to filter out the column `c4` based on `c2` when `c2 is true`?

Can someone guide me?

Comment: You should write out your data so that someone could easily copy / paste it.

Comment: and how should I do that? it'll be text anyways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without access to a JSFiddle I've created this:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
emailList = [];
table.rows().eq(0).each(function(index){
    var row = table.row(index);
    var data = row.data();
    (data[1] === "True" && emailList.indexOf(data[3]) === -1) && emailList.push(data[3]);
    return data[3];
});
console.log(emailList.join());
```

Working [here](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/afvp0azp/). Hope that helps.